# What is the Actual Meaning of cell.textLabel.text line in tableview datasource?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, cell

I am thinking about asking this question from sometime..

Now I am finally asking it..

When I say ...in the tableView datasource... that..

`cell.textLabel.text=[myArray ObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

what does it actually mean?? can anyone translate it for me from machine language??

I am using it a lot but ..I think I actually dont know what it does inside??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITableViewCell`(`cell` is object of this class) has few `subviews` added on it, one of them is referred by `textLabel`. `textLabel` is `UILabel` object and it is declared as property in `UITableViewCell` so that we can access it using `UITableViewCell` object. `text` is property of `UILabel` which helps to set `text` apearing on label. So cell gives you `UITableViewCell` then you access `textLabel` and set its `text` property.

`[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` is call for accessing an object from array(`myArray`) with given index. Here myArray should return `NSString` as its object so that it could be set as `text` of `textLabel`.

`objetAtIndex` is method that will return you array element located at given index. as we do for examle in C , `myArray[0]--->  [] bracket is for our (primitive type) data retrieval at given index in bracket.` 
In `object-c` you have this method,`objectAtIndex:`(defined for `NSArray`), does the same work.

`indexPath.row` denotes we are accessing `row` property of `indexPath`(`NSIndexPath` object)[similarly it has section property ] . and `" . "` is operator for accessing the properties.

more detailed insights are available in apple documentation.
Thanks,

Comment: @Ravin...Thanks Man...okay first part is clear...but in [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];...what is objectAtIndex?? is it something which fills indexPath.row means cell as per the elements of array..means first element of array in cell 1 then cell 2 ...and it goes on..is it something like that?

Answer (score 2):

This Cell is the UITableViewCell on which you can show the text. To showing text on Cell there is UILabel property in UITableViewCell and you can access that property using cell.textLabel.

now again UILabel is class and it has text property to show text so you can set text using text Property.

so you can access like

> cell.textLabel.text = @"Any string";

Hope this helps

Comment: so here cell is not the class but it is an object of UITableViewCell class...Am I getting it right??

Answer (score 1):

**[From apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

**textLabel**

Returns the label used for the main textual content of the table cell. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel *textLabel
```

**Discussion**

Holds the main label of the cell. UITableViewCell adds an appropriate label when you create the cell in a given cell style. See “Cell Styles” for descriptions of the main label in currently defined cell styles.

As far as your code line concerned,

```
cell.textLabel.text=[myArray ObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You are getting a `NSString` object from `myArray` At index `indexPath.row`, and assigning  it to `text` property of UILabel (textLabel).